# RabbitMq consumer registration and ports

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am using SPRING AMQP to connect with rabbitMq broker. I have a question about the registration process.
Why I do not need to expose additional port when running consumer in docker container? 
I am using asynchronous listener for messages in my Java app.

When I start rabbitMq:management docker image, it has port 5672 exposed to receive messages from publishers. Why does consumer not need to have also port exposed for rabbit broker to receive messages from it?

I have searched the rabbit webpage https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumers.html#subscribing but not much have been written. Maybe there is something I do not understand about networking here.

I am looking forward for any ideas. 
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to expose any ports on your consumer because, consumer app is subscribing on RabbitMQ to get events. That means that your consumer is making a call to RabbitMQ allowing it to know that it is listening and to make calls from Docker container you don't need to open ports.

More details on how consuming works in [RabbitMQ.](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#consuming)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am familiar with a webpage, but couldn;t understand the registration and connection.
is ti working like this: 
Consumer connects to rabbitmq and this connection is active until message is pushed to it ? 
Basically, it is consumer who connects to rabbitmq container all the time?

Comment: To my understanding yes, its pretty much works as websockets. Didn't found exact line of code in SPRING AMQP which does that.

Comment: Thanks, that really helped to shine some light on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

By default most of the default base images allow all outgress connections , it is only the ingress connections which require us to expose the requires PORT on the docker image.

Also if you want to block any specific incoming or outgoing networks you can do something like this in your entrypoint.
Sh script file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

#
# iptables configuration
#
# The following allows in- and outbound traffic
# within a certain `CIDR` (default: `192.168.0.0/24`),
# but blocks all other network traffic.
#
ACCEPT_CIDR=${ALLOWED_CIDR:-192.168.0.0/24}

iptables -A INPUT -s $ACCEPT_CIDR -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -d $ACCEPT_CIDR -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP

#
# After configuring `iptables` as root, execute
# the passed command as the non-privileged `app` user.
#
sudo -u app sh -c "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question is more about registration to rabbit and how this connection works. 
As Marius mentioned in his answer, the consumer is connecting to rabbitmq and waiting for push messages.